# Error converting 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PictureObject'

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have an image stored in a database and I want to insert it into one of the fields on a Crystal report. But I encounter this error:

> Error  25  Value of type 'System.Drawing.Image' cannot be converted to 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PictureObject'.

This is my code:

```
QR_Pic.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(msi, True)
QR_CodePic = CType(rptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("QR_Pic"), 
                   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PictureObject)
QR_CodePic.??? = QR_Pic.BackgroundImage
```

Comment: You cannot assign an object to a variable of a type that that object isn't. An `Image` object is not type `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PictureObject` so you can't assign it to a variable of that type. You should read the appropriate documentation and learn how to create an object of that type from an `Image`.  There may be a method or constructor that will do it for you but it won't happen by magic.

Comment: Apart from that, your code doesn't really make sense. The second line gets a `PictureObject` from a report and then assigns it to a variable, then the third line immediately assigns something else to that variable, so what was the point of the second line? Would you go to the effort of painting a wall blue if you knew that it was going to be painted red immediately afterwards, thus rendering what you did pointless? That what that code is doing.  Maybe you need to think a bit harder about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry that my code confused you, as the third line of the code should be `QR_CodePic.??? = QR_Pic.BackgroundImage` instead of `QR_CodePic = QR_Pic.BackgroundImage`.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked the question you actually wanted answered.  It seems to me that you are going about this all wrong.  I don't use CR but I simply searched the web for the `PictureObject` class and everything seems to suggest that what you're doing is way off base.  E.g. https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3168126